# Git difftool show multiple files in parallel

Tags: git

`git difftool` can be configured to use external visual diff program, like Araxis Merge or kdiff.

Unfortunately `git` does it in one-by-one manner with quite significant delay between each file.

Obviously each modern diff application supports comparing of multiple files at same time, either through tabs or multiple instances. Having multiple diffs opened simultaneously is convenient, for example when adding some feature caused changes in multiple files and you want be able to see them in any order, unlimited number of times, etc.

Is there way to cause `git difftool` run all diffs in parallel?

Comment: are you looking for `git difftool --dir-diff` (or the shorter `git difftool -d`) ?

Comment: eem... not exactly, but I think this can work too. Thanks!

Comment: I posted the `difftool -d` as an answer. Do you have a more specific need, which you could perhaps describe in more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git difftool` has a `-d|--dir-diff` option which will open your graphical diff viewer on two *directories*.

You can run this to compare any two commits, or a commit against your worktree or your index:

```
git difftool -d                 # compare your worktree to the index
git difftool -d HEAD            # compare your worktree to current commit
git difftool -d --cached        # compare your index to current commit
git difftool -d master HEAD     # compare two commits
git difftool -d master...HEAD   # (aka Pull Request view) compare your branch to
                                # the point when it forked from master
```

---

This command generally proceeds by copying the appropriate files in two temp directories, and then run `[diffcommand] dir1 dir2`.

So in general (e.g: when you run `git difftool -d branch1 branch2`), the files you edit through your diff viewer will be temp files, which will get deleted when you exit your diff viewer.

However, when one of the compared directories is your worktree (e.g: `git difftool -d somebranch [no second arg here]` or `git difftool -d --cached`), the "files" for the worktree side are symlinks, so you can edit files listed in the diff.

There still is a caveat to this last point: if you copy missing files to the "worktree" side of the diff, you are actually adding a file to the temporary directory -- and it will get deleted after you exit.

You will have to resort to other commands to copy such files (like `git restore -W -s <branch> -- that/file`) or open a file navigator and manually copy the files from your temp directory to your actual repo.

Comment: I actually checked this before asking the question, but I was confused that `git` copies files to temporary directory. So I thought that files cannot be edited. After your comment I checked more thoroughly and turns out that `git` copies updated files back to branch upon Araxis closure. A bit less convenient that I wanted, since requires closing diff, but it is better than nothing. Thank you

Comment: @Noob: I updated my answer to clarify what happens with these temp directory and files